# xcode - prepareForSegue with multiple identifiers

Tags: xcode, swift, segue, identifier

I have a tableView (not static cells) with two sections 
A bar section and a club section( and each has several cells). I want that every cell from the same section goes to the same viewcontroller.

I can only acces the first one, never the last one. Even de cells from the second section go to the first viewcontroller.

Can someone see my mistake?

```
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 2
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if section == 0 {
    return areas.bars.count
    } else {

    return areas.clubs.count
}
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mainIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    if  indexPath.section == 0 {
        let bars = areas.bars
        let bar = bars[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = bar.name

        return cell
    } else {
        let clubs = areas.clubs
        let club = clubs[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = club.name

        return cell
    }
}
```

the segue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "barsandclubsIdentifier"{
        let selectedIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let selectedBar = self.areas.bars[selectedIndex.row]
       let detailBarsAndClubsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailBarOrClubViewController
    detailBarsAndClubsViewController.bars = selectedBar
    }
     else {
        let selectedIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let selectedClub = self.areas.clubs[selectedIndex.row]
        let detailBarsAndClubsTwoViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailBarOrClubTwoViewController
        detailBarsAndClubsTwoViewController.clubs = selectedClub

    }
```

Comment: What happens when you click the cell?

Comment: the cells in section 0 go to the DetailBarOrClubViewController, and the cells in section need to go to another. At the moment they all go to DetailBarOrClubViewController.

Comment: How many dynamic prototype cells do you have in your storyboard?  If you are reusing the same cell for both sections, it will only segue to one of the view controllers.

Comment: That was it PetahChristian!!! thanks a million!! So stupid of me :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each prototype cell can only segue to a single viewController.  If you have 2 different destination viewControllers, you need 2 prototype cells: 1 for bars and 1 for clubs.  Give them each a unique identifier such as `"barCell"` and `"clubCell"`.

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, dequeue the proper cell:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellID = ["barCell", "clubCell"][indexPath.section]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID, forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

Then you can wire each prototype cell to go to the appropriate viewController.  Give each of these two segues a unique identifier such as `"barSegue"` and `"clubSegue"` and then you can use those in `prepareForSegue` to configure the destination viewController.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "barSegue"{
        let selectedIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let selectedBar = self.areas.bars[selectedIndex.row]
        let detailBarViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailBarViewController
        detailBarsViewController.bars = selectedBar
    }
    else if segue.identifier = "clubSegue" {
        let selectedIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let selectedClub = self.areas.clubs[selectedIndex.row]
        let detailClubViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailClubViewController
        detailClubsViewController.clubs = selectedClub
    }
}
```